# SDL mousewheel and mousemotion

Tags: c++, sdl

I made a previous question regarding mouse input which helped me understand mouse events worked for a start. I created a class that handles all kinds of input, and suffice it to say there are a few bugs which I've tried correcting with booleans but to no avail.

Mouse wheel and mousemotion events execute continuously even when the mouse wheel or mouse is not scrolling or moving.

I test for mouse scrolls with this simple call:

```
bool isMouseWheelScrolled() const
{
    return pMouseWheelScrolled;
}
```

Then I listen for mouse events using a switch statement:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            onMouseMove(event);
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:
            onMouseWheelScroll(event);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void onMouseWheelScroll(SDL_Event &event)
{
    switch(event.wheel.type)
    {
    case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:
        pMouseWheelScrolled = true;
        pMouseWheel.x = event.wheel.x;
        pMouseWheel.y = event.wheel.y;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The same thing applies in mouse movement, but:

```
void onMouseMove(SDL_Event &event)
{
    pMouseMoved = true;
    pMousePosition.x = event.motion.x;
    pMousePosition.y = event.motion.y;
}
```

It does have a problem with the booleans; the conditions for setting them to true are tested, but I don't know how I can analyse a condition for these booleans to become false. My solution would be to dwell into listening for mouse states, however I do not know how to do this and tutorials are insufficient in explaining them. The documentation isn't that intuitive either. The reason I need booleans is so I can test whether the mouse has moved or scrolled OUTSIDE the class. I can already test for key presses and mouse button presses; but mouse wheel and mouse moved are another issue; primarily because I need to obtain

```
event.motion.x; 
event.motion.y;
event.wheel.x;
event.wheel.y;
```

for my camera. And I am not prepared to pass camera into my class because that breaks OO.

tldr; mouse wheel and mouse moved are set to true, but how to disable them when the mouse wheel isn't scrolling or when the mouse isn't moving?

Comment: You never set pMouseWheelScrolled to false.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I set it to false in the default case and outside the switch statement. The latter causes it to be false all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how mouse events work. You do not get a `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event while the mouse is moving. Instead you get a `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event when the mouse is moved. That is, the event represents a single instant in time.

If you want to do something when the mouse is moved, your best option is to do it as direct response to the mouse event. If that goes against your OO design, then your design is wrong.‎‎‎‎

If you insist in using booleans, then you should set the boolean variable to `false` as soon as your consumer class sees it as `true`, so that each event is processed only once.

Anyway, my advice is to use some kind of interface, such as this one:

```
class IMouseListener
{
    virtual OnMouseMove(int x, int y) =0;
    virtual OnMouseWheel(int x, int y) =0;
};
```

Then make your main class implement this interface, and make your mouse handling code receive a pointer to such interface.

Comment: Is there another way other than booleans?

Comment: @Poriferous: Yes, as I wrote in my answer, the preferred way to program user input is with _event based programming_. Using the `IMouseListener` interface you will not need the booleans.

Comment: Ok, I'm not actually sure what you're asking here, bear with me. You want me to make an abstract class that InputHandler inherits; but how is this going to solve the problem? What should I even be implementing within those aforesaid functions?

Comment: @Poriferous: There are two different problems here: one is that you want mouse states (moving/still) while you only get mouse events (discrete positions). The other is that your have an outer class that has a reference to the mouse handling class, but I suggest that it is better the other way around. We can move into a chat room if you wish to discuss this further.

Comment: Sure, how do we proceed?

Comment: @Poriferous: Mmmm, the first time I start a chat room. Try going [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67395/sdl-mousewheel-and-mousemotion).